# Does Alphabet Case Matters while Training Stanford Open NLP NER classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, conditional-random-field, named-entity-recognition

I'm working with Named Entity Recognition for non-English. I've some raw text file (all small letter) and trying to make NER classifier. I'm not sure If it'll be better using Small Capital mixed text for training. Any Idea guys?

Answer (score 0):

Stanford NLP, being the wiz-kids that they are, take advantage of all information present in their annotators and models. That includes upper-case letters.

They describe a few work arounds, such as a truecaser or models that are less sensitive to that lack of information below:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/caseless.html

If your data is case insensitive, it will impact your results. I would suggest removing whatever piece of your pipeline is sanitizing case from your text, if you're able.